# What is csc2.exe?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015

What is csc2?

Visual Studio 2013 shipped with a commandline C# compiler `csc.exe` in `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin`. I sometimes used it to build little hello world apps eg. `csc hello-world.cs`

Visual Studio 2015 still ships with `csc.exe` but also a new `csc2.exe` in `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin`. What is `csc2.exe`? How's it different from `csc.exe`?

Comment: "csc2.exe and vbc2.exe. These are extremely small native executables that simply start or connect to a VBCSCompiler.exe process and send command line arguments to it. This allows the VBCSCompiler.exe process to reuse loaded assemblies for multiple projects." - [Source](http://roslyn.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Building%2C%20Testing%20and%20Debugging)

Comment: @DavidSherret That should be the answer… if you feel a quote is insufficient for reputation you could always flag it community wiki

Comment: @Richard ok, yeah, that's how i felt because i just googled it.

Comment: @DavidSherret: Sorry, missed your comment. If you want to add an answer, I will remove mine.

Comment: @PatrickHofman no man, that's cool. I shouldn't have commented.This site should be more of a team effort anyways.

Comment: According to Pythogaras `csc2 = 1 + tan2`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Those are part of Roslyn, the new open source .NET compiler platform.

From their [CodePlex page](http://roslyn.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Building%2C%20Testing%20and%20Debugging):

> **Building the command line compilers**
>
> Note that in most situations the compilers will NOT be invoked through csc and vbc for performance reasons, but they are the simplest way to debug. Other entry points include:
>
> 1. csc2.exe and vbc2.exe. These are extremely small native executables that simply start or connect to a VBCSCompiler.exe process and send command line arguments to it. This allows the VBCSCompiler.exe process to reuse loaded assemblies for multiple projects.

The source of `csc2` can be found [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/tree/master/src/Compilers/CSharp/csc2). As you can see, it is just a very small starter application.

Comment: Note that with https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/commit/2f77a182e77755349867c88e63c558788223d2c0 the native executables were replaced by managed ones.